# Is it normal to see stuttering and framerate drops in the flutter application?

Tags: dart, flutter

I can see a frame rate drops and stuttering in my flutter application while changing the views in the app. I was wondering whether it is normal or not. 
Also as a note i'm in the debug mode of the app.

Comment: It is not normal. Please take a look at this doc for debugging performance issues: https://flutter.io/ui-performance/.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell if it is normal, a problem with Flutter or a problem with your code.
It doesn't make too much sense to evaluate performance in debug builds because performance characteristics are quite different to release builds.

If you actually want to evaluate performance characteristics, use a `--release` or `--profile` build.

Comment: Thank you. Will look into it.